# Javascript/JQuery Searching in table for row by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

I have simple html table with one `<input type="text">`

```html
<input class="font-15 w-300-px" id="SomeID" type="text">
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header">
                <th style="width:20%;">One</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Two</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Three</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Four</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Five</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Six</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="www.w3school.com" target="_blank">
                            aaa
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="www.idk.com" target="_blank">
                            bb
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>ccc</td>
                    <td>dddd</td>
                    <td>eeee</td>
                    <td>ffff</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Then I have this script for filtering. `

```js
var $rows = $('#myTable tr:gt(0)');
        $('#SomeID').keyup(function () {
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.hide().filter(function () {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return ~text.indexOf(val);
            }).show();
        });
```

My problem is that filtering takes so long (I have a lot of rows). Is there any way possible to show only 150 rows or so? Is this good way of solving this problem? Should I be using some other way to filter? Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery Data table approch where it provide default searching and sorting function. You can add column specific searching also.

1. $("#Your_Table_Id").DataTable();
   Below line will convert your table into jquery datatable.

For more info click [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/styling/jqueryui.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 150 rows, use an iterator that will start at 0 and end at 150 and filter inside it, after you get to 150th row it should stop filtering. This is probably not an full-on answer as I'm not a Js dev, but try experimenting or searching in that direction while someone gives you a more precise answer.

There are a lot of answered question about iterating through tables, and I feel there is a better way to filter, like iterating through each row and defining an requirement with a If statement to determine if you want to do something with the row or go to the next one.